# Find locality given lat lng

Tags: google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

On a website, users click on a Google Map, I call the geocoding service and get all the available information for that given lat-lng.

I have a database of all provinces (areas) in Spain and the given municipalities for each area. I also have the lat-lng of every municipality (center-based). When I refer to municipality I guess is what Google calls 'locality'.

Now, I would like to match the point of the map clicked by the user, with it's corresponding municipality. How could I achieve that? Google response is not a valid key to search on a database and there might be spelling differences.

**Edit:** I found a site with a kml file per municipality, defining its area. I would need to parse every file and find the one that contains the coordinate clicked by the user. Could it be possible to translate those kml into a database for fast processing?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach IMO would be the use of postal-codes. When you have postal-codes stored for  every municipality you may fetch the postal-code out of the geocoding-result and use it to query the DB.

When you don't have the postal-codes(or anything else that gives you a distinct relationship between the geocoding-result and your database) stored , you may use the bounds (you'll find it in the geometry of the result) to query the database for a point within the bounds.

Comment: Unfortunatelly Postal Code are not unique: two localities may share a postal code.

Comment: In spain 2 municipalities(that's what we talk about) may share a postal- code?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the geometries in a PostGIS database, and run GeoServer to respond to these queries.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your edit: It's certainly possible to do **point-in-polygon analysis**. A geo-enabled database makes it easy, and it's possible to do it with a non-geo database. Some GIS databases only use a bounding rectangle, not the actual polygon. With a non-geo database you need to code it yourself, so it's possible to use the actual boundary data. See solution 1 at http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/insidepoly/